# .NET Core build in docker linux container fails due to SSL authentication to Nuget

Tags: linux, docker, .net-core, nuget, containers

I was given a .NET Core project to run in a Linux Docker container to do the build, everything seems to be okay on the docker configuration side, but when I run this command: `dotnet publish -c Release -o out`, I get the SSL authentication error below.

`The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception. Authentication failed because the remote party has closed the transport stream.`

I did my research and apparently it seemed that I was missing:

1. the environment variables Kestrel for ASPNET (as per https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore.Docs/issues/6199), which I add to my `docker-compose`, but I don't think it is the issue.
2. a Developer .pfx certificate, so I updated my `docker-compose` with the Kestrel Path to the certs file as seen below.

```
version: '3'
services:
  netcore:
    container_name: test_alerting_comp
    tty: true
    stdin_open: true
    image: alerting_netcore
    environment:
      - http_proxy=http://someproxy:8080
      - https_proxy=http://someproxy:8080
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
      - ASPNETCORE_URLS=https://+;http://+
      - ASPNETCORE_HTTPS_PORT=443
      - ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Password="ABC" 
      - ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Path=/root/.dotnet/corefx/cryptography/x509stores/my
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
      - "443:443"  
    build: .
      #context: .
    security_opt:
      - seccomp:unconfined
    volumes:
      - "c:/FakePath/git/my_project/src:/app"
      - "c:/TEMP/nuget:/root"
    networks:
      - net
networks:
  net:
```

I re-run the docker container and executed `dotnet publish -c Release -o out` with the same results.

From my host I can do this to my local NuGet:

A) `wget https://nuget.local.com/api/v2` without issues,

B) but from the container I can't.

C) However from the container I can do this to official NuGet `wget https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json`, so definetely my proxy is working okay.

Debugging SSL issue:

The given .pfx certificate is a self-signed one, and it is working okay from Windows OS (at least I was told that).

1. `strace` shows me from where the certs are being pulled from as below

`root@9b98d5447904:/app# strace wget https://nuget.local.com/api/v2 |& grep certs open("/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt", O_RDONLY) = 3`

2. I exported the .pfx as follows:
   `openssl pkcs12 -in ADPRootCertificate.pfx -out my_adp_dev.crt` then moved it to `/usr/local/share/ca-certificates/`, removed the private part, just left in the file public part (`-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE----- -----END CERTIFICATE-----` ) executed `update-ca-certificates` and I could see `1 added`, double checked in file `/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt` and the new cert was in there.
3. Executed this again `wget https://nuget.local.com/api/v2` and failed.
4. I used OpenSSL to get more info and as you can see it is not working, the cert has a weird CN, because they used a wildcard for the subject and to me this is wrong, but they state that .pfx is working in Windows OS.

```
root@ce21098e9643:/usr/local/share/ca-certificates# openssl s_client -connect nuget.local.com:443 -CApath /etc/ssl/certs
CONNECTED(00000003)
depth=0 CN = *.local.com
verify error:num=20:unable to get local issuer certificate
verify return:1
depth=0 CN = *.local.com
verify error:num=21:unable to verify the first certificate
verify return:1
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:/CN=\x00*\x00l\x00o\x00c\x00a\x00l\x00.\x00c\x00o\x00m
   i:/C=ES/ST=SomeCity/L=SomeCity/OU=DEV/O=ASD/CN=Development CA
---
Server certificate
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
XXXXXXXXXXX
XXXXXXXXXXX
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
subject=s:/CN=\x00*\x00l\x00o\x00c\x00a\x00l\x00.\x00c\x00o\x00m
issuer=i:/C=ES/ST=SomeCity/L=SomeCity/OU=DEV/O=ASD/CN=Development CA
---
No client certificate CA names sent
Peer signing digest: SHA1
Server Temp Key: ECDH, P-256, 256 bits
---
SSL handshake has read 1284 bytes and written 358 bytes
Verification error: unable to verify the first certificate
---
New, TLSv1.2, Cipher is ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384
Server public key is 1024 bit
Secure Renegotiation IS supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1.2
    Cipher    : ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384
    Session-ID: 95410000753146AAE1D313E8538972244C7B79A60DAF3AA14206417490E703F3
    Session-ID-ctx:
    Master-Key: B09214XXXXXXX0007D126D24D306BB763673EC52XXXXXXB153D310B22C341200EF013BC991XXXXXXX888C08A954265623
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    SRP username: None
    Start Time: 1558993408
    Timeout   : 7200 (sec)
    Verify return code: 21 (unable to verify the first certificate)
    Extended master secret: yes
---
```

I don't know what issue I'm facing, but it appears to be that:

A) the self-signed .pfx was wrongly configured, and now that it is being used in Linux it doesn't work as it should.

B) I need some more config in the container, which I'm not aware of.

What else should I do?

I'm thinking on probaly create other cert to use from Linux hosts.

Is it feasible to create another self-signed cert with OpenSSL for IIS ver 8 and import it to IIS?.

Any ideas are welcome, cheers.

Comment: possibly related: https://medium.com/gsoft-tech/certificates-in-net-core-on-linux-and-docker-29b3d5f09cd6

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**ANSWERING TO MYSELF**

It was not a Linux container issue, **it is a certificate issue in the web server (IIS), because we are using self-signed certificates and in this way the cert will be always an `invalid certificate`**. Self-signed certs works okay on Windows OS side, doesn't matter the invalid error. *Of course self-signed certs are just for a test environment or so.*

From Linux OS when you are trying to pull packages from NuGet you will get the error below, because:

1) The cert is indeed invalid, and

2) because apparently there is not an option to ignore an invalid certificate from Linux side.

```
The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception.
The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure.
```

**The solution** is you are working in a corporate environment, is to request to System Administrator a proper signed certificate, for that you generate a CSR from your web server, in my case IIS, then pass it to them, so they will send you back a .cer file to install in that web server.

**The other option that I was trying to do** but I couldn't due to the limitations of my corporate environment, is to create a fake CA (with OpenSSL), then you sign the CSR's yourself to have some valid certificates for your Dev or test environment.

Apologizes for answering this myself, but I believe it is worth to share my findings.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. Docker build would not restore my nugets.

`Unable to load the service index for source https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json.`

`The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception.`

`Authentication failed because the remote party has closed the transport stream.`

(On a Mac running Catalina)
I turned off Fiddler and then it all worked again.

Comment: am getting the same issue fro telerik packages also am not using any fiddler, any insights what I may go wrong here